# History and excerpt history links on the tag info page are on different lines on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design, tag-wiki, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Stack Overflow in English:

> [image]

Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image]

As I can see, class `post-menu` on ru SO has width limitations on this block:

```
.post-menu {
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 240px;
}
```